# C++: Function with buffer and pointer loop - Possibilities for optimization?

Tags: c++, pointers

I wrote a function to convert an image with two bytes to a 8-bit image by taking only the upper bytes.

I still need the original image and so cannot modify the original array.

This function is called to process each frame of a video stream.

Do you know possibilities to optimize the function for speed?

Thanks!

```
QImage* createQImage(uchar *ptr, uint width, uint height, uint channels)
{
   static uint size = width * height * channels;
   static uchar *buffer = new uchar[size];


   //Take every second byte (upper byte)
   for(uint i=0; i<size; i++) {
       buffer[i] = (*(ptr+1));
       ptr = ptr+2;
   }

   static QImage img = QImage(buffer, width, height, QImage::Format_BGR888);
   static QImage *ptr_img = &img;

   return ptr_img;
}
```

Comment: Having a `static` variable and returning a pointer to it looks pretty dangerous (especially in a multithreaded context). How about taking the output image as argument, and writing the result to it directly?

Comment: In addition to never using `static` like that, this whole thing seems like an exercise in SIMD operations. Crack open a book on AVX instructions and get coding!

Comment: Actually, with the proper compiler options (something like `-march=native`), I would expect modern compilers to be able to automatically vectorize this simple loop. If not, I would first check if there are some compiler pragmas you could add to make it happen rather than writing intrinsics by hand.

Comment: If you are just moving an input buffer to an output buffer doing it one byte at a time isn't the fastest. Simply casting `uchar *ptr` to `uint64_t*` and pulling out the bytes using bit shifting/masks maybe the way to optimise this. You will end up with some bytes left at the end that you will need to process manually. In the same way that you already are. Assuming that you images are 16bit then 16/64 == 4, giving you a 4 times code improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just moving an input buffer to an output buffer doing it one byte at a time isn't the fastest. Simply casting `uchar *ptr` to `uint64_t*` and pulling out the bytes using bit shifting/masks maybe the way to optimise this. You will end up with some bytes left at the end that you will need to process "manually", in the same way that you already are. Assuming that your images are 16-bit then 16/64 == 4, giving you a 4 times speed improvement.

This assumes that your hardware can load 64 bits at a time, you could make this code load 32 bits at a time by using `uint32_t` instead but it is a fair assumption that most people have 64 bit hardware. The code assumes you are using little endian hardware.

The code (untested).

```
QImage* createQImage(uchar* ptr, uint width, uint height, uint channels) {
    uint64_t* nptr = (uint64_t*)ptr;

    static uint size = width * height * channels;
    static uchar *buffer = new uchar[size];
    static uint bytesize = size*2;

    uint idx = 0;
    uint i = 0;
    for(; i + sizeof(uint64_t) <= bytesize; i+=sizeof(uint64_t)) {
        //get 64 bits at a time
        uint64_t val = nptr[i/sizeof(uint64_t)];

        //get 4 bytes at a time
        //note inverted due to little endian assumed (maybe wrong)
        buffer[idx] = (uchar)(val >> (8 * 6));
        ++idx;
        buffer[idx] = (uchar)(val >> (8 * 4));
        ++idx;
        buffer[idx] = (uchar)(val >> (8 * 2));
        ++idx;
        buffer[idx] = (uchar)(val >> (8 * 0));
        ++idx;
    }

    //We have some bytes left at the end, process these a byte at a time
    //Take every second byte (upper byte)
    for(; i < bytesize; i+=2) {
        buffer[idx] = (*(ptr + i + 1));
        ++idx;
    }

    static QImage img = QImage(buffer, width, height, QImage::Format_BGR888);
    static QImage *ptr_img = &img;

    return ptr_img;
}
```